# Bring the last date (result)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I'm trying to bring the mostly recent date with the query below:

```
select id, amount, yearmonthday
from ( 
select 
id,
amount,
yearmonthday,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY try(date_parse(yearmonthday, '%Y-%m-%d'))) as row_num 
from "db_raw"."table" ) ranked
where row_num = 1 and id = 1
```

But every time i run the query, brings me a different result not the last date

run for the first time, brings what i want:

| id | amount | yearmonthday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10000 | 20231213 |

if i run again, brings me other result:

| id | amount | yearmonthday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9000 | 20230327 |

Comment: Could you add some simple data and the expected output

Comment: Please add sample data, especially actual `yearmonthday` values

Comment: A [mre] ***must*** include sample data and desired results for that sample data ; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: @GuruStron thanks

Comment: @WilliamSoares see update in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to sort in descending order to get the most resent date (assuming dates in the past):

```
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id 
     ORDER BY try(date_parse(yearmonthday, '%Y-%m-%d')) desc) as row_num
```

default sorting order is ascending.

Also note that:

- You can have several rows for the same date per partition in data, in this case you will get a random one amongst the "duplicates"
- `try(...)` will swallow parsing errors resulting in `null` so make sure that date it actually parsed otherwise you will not actually order the output. Add `try(date_parse(yearmonthday, '%Y-%m-%d')` to the select results and see if it is not null (also you can count all unparsable rows with `select count(*) from ... where  try(date_parse(yearmonthday, '%Y-%m-%d') is null`)

**UPD**

The second note was correct - you parse date using incorrect format, `yearmonthday` does not have delimiters, so remove them:

```
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id 
     ORDER BY try(date_parse(yearmonthday, '%Y%m%d')) desc) as row_num
```